# Fields of hstore emptying if validation fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, hstore

Rails 4.2
PostgreSQL 9.3.7

I'm using `hstore` to store some data in key-value format.

```ruby
create_table "lang", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.hstore   "dictionary"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

In the model I use some validations via store_accessor

```ruby
store_accessor :dictionary, :foo, :bar
validates_presence_of :foo, :bar
```

Part of `new` action view in `slim` format:

```ruby
= form_for(@lang) do |f|
  .field
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name
  .field
    = f.fields_for :dictionary do |dic_form|
      fieldset
        = dic_form.label :foo
        = dic_form.text_field :foo
        br
        = dic_form.label :bar
        = dic_form.text_field :bar
  .actions = f.submit
```

Why when validation check fails all data I typed in inputs are emptied?
Eg: I typed only `test` text in `foo` field, submit form. See error explanation but `test` text are disappeared from `foo` field.

Is there any way to make data persist between requests like in normal rails forms?

Comment: Could you please show your controller, with an emphasise on strong_params

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in how rails form extract attributes.
When I type

```
= form_for(@lang) do |f|
  .field
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name
```

Rails evals `@lang.name`

So when the form looks like this

```
= f.fields_for :dictionary do |dic_form|
  .fieldset
    = dic_form.label :foo
    = dic_form.text_field :foo
```

There is no result from `@lang.dictionary.foo` code.

Solution here is to use OpenStruct like:

```
= form_for(@lang) do |f|
  .field
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name
  .field
    = f.fields_for :dictionary, OpenStruct.new(@translation.dictionary) do |dic_form|
      fieldset
        = dic_form.label :foo
        = dic_form.text_field :foo
        br
        = dic_form.label :bar
        = dic_form.text_field :bar
  .actions = f.submit
```